# Matching Products in an Array list against another Array list for similar products

Tags: java, regex

I have two array lists. One array list contains foreign food products while other array list contains local food products.

Array list which holds foreign products : capturedForeginProduct

Sample data for the ***capturedForeginProduct*** array list

> Ebony Garlic
>
> Tell Tale Elephant Garlic
>
> High Top Garlic
>
> Carrington Lemon Popsicles

Array list which holds local products : capturedLocalProducts

> NOAS Garlic Murukku 100g
>
> SMAK Garlic Bites 100g
>
> CIC Chilli & Garlic Sauce 400g
>
> KIST Lemon & Mint Nectar 1L

I want to list down local products that match with foreign product.

I use following code to get the output.

```
for (int i = 0; i < capturedForeginProduct.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < capturedLocalProducts.size(); j++) {
                //   if(capturedForeginProduct.get(i).contains("Garlic")) {
                if (Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(capturedLocalProducts.get(j)), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(capturedForeginProduct.get(i)).find() || capturedLocalProducts.get(j).toLowerCase().contains(capturedForeginProduct.get(i).toLowerCase())) {
                    log.debug("Matching .. : " + "\t" + capturedForeginProduct.get(i) + "\t" + capturedLocalProducts.get(j));
                    firstForeignProducts.add(capturedForeginProduct.get(i));
                    firstLocalProducts.add(capturedLocalProducts.get(j));
                }
                else {
                }
            }
        }
```

This what I want to be done ...

> Ebony Garlic should match NOAS Garlic Murukku 100g
>
> Tell Tale Elephant Garlic should match SMAK Garlic Bites 100g

Is there another way to achieve this goal ? Any algorithm is accepted.

Comment: What do you mean by "local products that match with foreign product"? Could you give some example with explanation which is correct result and which is not?

Comment: What algorithm do you want to use to match "Ebony Garlic" to "NOAS Garlic Murukku 100g"?

Comment: @Kenster Its up to you.. I dont mind using any algo. My need is to match products accurately.

Comment: @DulithDeCozta The confusion is not on how to go about the process but on what the definition of accurate "matching" for products is-- it is unclear why `Ebony Garlic` matches `NOAS Garlic Murukku 100g` but `High Top Garlic` does not match `CIC Chilli & Garlic Sauce 400g`

Comment: @Saposhiente bascially what i want to do is .. I want to match local products against foreign product. Eg. High top garlic contains the word GARLIC so do CIC chilli and Garlic sauce. In this example it should be matched then as both contains GARLIC.

Comment: @DulithDeCozta Is the definition therefore that the products must have at least one word in common? Are there any concerns about eg. matching "a" or "&" between products? This doesn't seem like a real-world useful definition of matching.

Comment: I'm hvn an algo which merges two datasets. So i think it is useful. Anyways it is for my office work. Yes. No concerns like that. No matter about the case sensitivity. Just to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to find all local products that contain a word which is also contained in at least one foreign product. Rather than iterating through every possible combination of products and words (O(n^2*length^2)), collect every word used in a foreign product into a `HashSet`, then for each local product check whether the set contains any of the words in the local product.

Note that your method for checking for matches is incorrect: it, by two different methods, checks whether the descriptions are exactly equal ignoring case; you must instead use `String.split(" ")` to get the words in the products and then iterate through the words to check for matches.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. Is not it the same I have done using for loops ? I want to know about a pattern matching just like the one i have used. :)

Comment: @DulithDeCozta Your solution checks every possible combination of products for a match; my solution instead compiles all the foreign product words into a sorted list that you can swiftly check for whether it contains a given word. It is O(n) rather than O(n^2); i.e. for a list of 1000 items this is 1000 times faster. In addition, your use of Pattern simply does not work (see my edit); if you are insistent on using Pattern you must modify the pattern to check for individual words rather than the entire string.

Answer (score 0):

You could create two Enumerations that hold this information, give those ordinals values that correlate with their respected foods, then create and loop through an ArrayList for each Enumration and match the information.

Comment: your procedure did not work out. Any other way of doing it @Coleton ?